# Is there no WebGL implementation in Opera 12.0?

Tags: opera, webgl

I am trying to get WebGL running with Opera 12.0 (Mac OS X Lion).
The [Opera Website](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2011/10/13/introducing-opera-12-alpha) states that WebGL is supported, although if I check it via the [WebGL check](http://get.webgl.org/) website, Opera doesn't really seem to work.

Everything I tried is working fine in latest Chrome.

Is there anything I have to change in Opera's prefs to enable WebGL or is it just not supported at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `opera:gpu` and see if your video card is block-listed.
If there is a text: `Vega backend: Software`, it means HW Acceleration got auto disabled because of previous crashes ;) Easiest fix is re-installation. Or separate side-by-side installation.

I have had a similar problem yesterday, now its fixed - and i can see:

- http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Demo_Repository
- http://maps3d.svc.nokia.com/webgl/

For google webgl experiments - many of them do not work even in chrome 17.

Comment: Did fresh install. Still says Vega backend: Software.

Comment: Quite possibly that either your Mac graphics card, or its drivers are not compatible with Opera. This might be fixed in future, or not, depending on the relative frequency of such hardware/software configuration and its age. Good luck with it.

Comment: I'll contact the Opera dev team about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have webGL enabled in options which are acessible through url:

```
opera:config
```

just type `webgl` in search input